# Formula to find the sum of nth row?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

In the following triangle I need to find the sum of nth row. Is there a general formula for this? If yes, then please tell me.

- Triangle:
- Row 1:         1
- Row 2:       1 2 1
- Row 3:     1 3 6 3 1
- Row 4:   1 4 10 20 10 4 1
- Row 5: 1 5 15 35 70 35 15 5 1
- etc.

S(n) = sum of nth row.

Like,
S(1) = 1
S(2) = 4
S(3) = 14
S(4) = 50
etc..

Find S(n)?

---

An attempt to show how the triangle is constructed

$$\binom 00$$
$$\binom 10\binom 21\binom 10$$
$$\binom20\binom31\binom 42\binom 31\binom 20$$
$$\binom 30\binom 41\binom 52\binom 63\binom 52\binom 41\binom 30$$

etc with the middle of row $r$ being $\binom {2r-2}{r-1}$ which is the V-shaped extracts fromPascal's Triangle noted in my comment below.

Another equivalent way, which may be more useful is $$\binom 00$$$$
\binom 11\binom 21\binom 11$$$$\binom 22\binom 32\binom 42\binom 32\binom 22$$

etc

[image: Triangle]

Comment: There should be a row between Row 1 and Row 2 which is 1 1.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Note this is not Pascal's Triangle - though clearly closely related. Each row has an odd number of entries. The sums seem to satisfy $S(r+1)=3S(r)+2^{r-1}$, but it would be useful to have a note on how the triangle is constructed before reaching a definitive conclusion. It looks as though you get it by taking successive V-shaped slices from Pascal's Triangle.

Comment: I have posted an edit to show how I think the triangle is constructed.

Comment: @MarkBennet:  if you count the rows starting at $0$, the center of row $r$ becomes ${2r \choose r}$ and we are looking for $\left(\sum_{i=0}^{r-1}2{r+i \choose i} \right)+{2r \choose r}=\left(\sum_{i=0}^{r-1}2{r+i \choose r} \right)+{2r \choose r}$

Comment: @RossMillikan Thanks. I didn't want to disturb the original numbering, but that formulation looks more convenient.

Comment: http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C4%2C14%2C50%2C182&sort=&language=english&go=Search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we count the rows starting at zero, the sum of row $r$ is $$2\left(\sum_{i=0}^{r-1}  {r+i \choose i}\right) + {2r \choose r}$$  It starts off $1,4,14,50,182,672$, which picks out [OEIS A051924](http://oeis.org/A051924)  The last comment says these are the hook sums of Pascal's triangle and there is an explicit formula ${2n \choose n}-{2n-2 \choose n-1}$.  This starts counting at $1$, not $0$

Comment: A combinatorial reason for this is that the sum you have can be rewritten with the terms $\binom {r+i}r$ and this can be computed as the number of ways of selecting $r+1$ items out of $2r$ (of which the first is the smallest - choosing different smallest numbers first gives the sum) - hence the sum is $\binom {2r}{r+1}$ and an alternative formula is $2\binom {2r}{r+1}+\binom {2r}r$ - this is equal to the one you have given.